# How to prevent Maven from compiling classes in src/test/java, which are generated during the generate-sources phase?

Tags: java, maven

In our jOOQ integration tests, we're using the jOOQ code generation plugin to generate classes into the `src/test/java` directory. We're doing that because:

- We want to check in generated sources, so we can detect regressions in the code generator more easily
- The generated classes are used by the tests

So, the (simplified) plugin configuration looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>some-id</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <generator>
          <target>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
          </target>
        </generator>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, this seems to lead Maven to believe that the classes thus generated need to be compiled as well during the `compile` phase, as can be seen in the following log output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ... ---
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to C:\...\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ... ---
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to C:\...\target\test-classes
```

... which makes no sense at all. Debug output hints at both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` being included as `compileSourceRoots`:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [C:\...\src\main\java, C:\...\src\test\java]
```

For the record, during the `testCompile` phase, as expected, only `src/test/java` is placed on the `compileSourceRoots` path:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [C:\...\src\test\java]
```

For the record, we're using Maven 3.6.2

How can I prevent the `src/test/java` directory from being added to the `compileSourceRoots` variable?

Comment: You can simply do `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: @papaya: No, I cannot. In fact, I can't even `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`. But the question is more complex than what you may be thinking.

Comment: Would it be an option to change the execution phase from `generate-sources` to `generate-test-sources`?

Comment: @DavidJansen: Yes, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225035/521799), although I would like to 1) avoid it, 2) at least understand why this is happening.

Comment: So you would like exclude the compilation of generated class in src/test/java ? But doesn't this mean that your tests are also not compilable ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @SaifAsif: I don't want to compile `src/test/java` content during the `compile` phase, because "obviously", that directory should be compiled only during the `testCompile` phase.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (not very pretty) is to exclude the test classes from the compiler plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/example/test/**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Another is to use the `generate-test-sources` phase, which we avoided so far, because of some unrelated side effects that we wanted to test already before the `compile` phase:

```xml
<phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
```

I'm definitely hoping for a better solution!